# How redirect to alogin page in html Django if user is not authinticated

Tags: html, django

How to in HtMl to redirect user if it is noit registered using this template. I want to redirect if not registered to Login page

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Authenticated user</p>
{% else %}
    redirect to 'login' page
{% endif %}
```

I have in settings.py

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
```

Answer (score 0):

Template is not place to do redirects on

Use [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator on view instead

Comment: there is an example in documentation i linked to, show us your view

Answer (score -1):

redirect doesn't work within the Django template.  To redirect you can try some of the [decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) that Django has provided us.

Just in your view.py do as I did.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
```

In this example, the @login_required decorator checks if the user has logged in.  If not, it will redirect the user to the route specified in the LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL.

Otherwise, if you wish to do this check in the template, you can try some thing like this.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Authenticated user</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Create a view here which tells the user to login. </p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
user = authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
```

if user is not None:
# A backend authenticated the credentials
else:
# No backend authenticated the credentials